# Color transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to make a color transition but I don't know how to make the effect that the color will be added gradually without increase size.

```css
     a:hover{
        background-color:#c0392b; 
        transition: 1000ms linear;
        padding:20px;
```

```html
        <nav class="navigation-in-center">
            <ul class="container menu group">
                <li><a href="#">A PROPOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IDEES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CHEQUES CADEUX</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your size is increasing due to `padding`.
Remove the `padding` and apply `transition` to the `a` element, not in it's hover state:

```css
a {
  transition: all 1000ms linear;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation-in-center">
  <ul class="container menu group">
    <li><a href="#">A PROPOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">IDEES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CHEQUES CADEUX</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a transition for "background-color" only.
transition: background-color 1000ms linear;

```css
a{
display: inline-block;
  padding:20px;
   transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
a:hover{
        background-color:#c0392b; 
       }
```

```html
<nav class="navigation-in-center">
            <ul class="container menu group">
                <li><a href="#">A PROPOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IDEES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CHEQUES CADEUX</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```